# Column not updating having array - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an column where array gets saved into database and I have made casts into model

Model

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'location',
    'country_id',
    'website',
    'phone',
    'images',
];

protected $casts = [
    'images' => 'array',
];
```

Now I have a functionality where I have to remove an element from an array and save it again back to table but I don't know the column does not updates.

```php
public function removeImage($id, Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->image;
    $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
    $images = $project->images;
    if (($key = array_search($image, $images)) !== false) {
        unset($images[$key]);
        $imagesArray = array_values(array_filter($images));
        $project->images = $imagesArray;
        $project->save();
        $file = public_path('uploads/'.$image);
        File::delete($file);
    }
}
```

The Column is saving like this:

```
["projects\/\/9e14acf681eb26b860bab49bb5da3579.jpg","projects\/\/8f5fbb1bc517eba0f9a229b505a48e1d.jpg","projects\/\/7a1a3dc5c614fb4d9c3dfae0e0200c99.jpg"]
```

I don't know but the updated array is not updating into column.
Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean it remains unchanged without update?

Comment: Try `Log::info($images);Log::info($image);` (then check your Laravel log file for the results) to see if the values match exactly. You have double slashes in your paths, and you don't show if `$image` is the full relative path or just the file name.

Comment: What if you do `$project->fill(['images' => json_encode($imagesArray)])->save();` ? I could be wrong, but I think `$casts` are just getters.